# how can i read new inserted data from a FMDatabase

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

My app reads some data from an fmdatabase and shows it graphically using core plot library. All is good the first time my app reads the DB but the problem is that after inserting new data into the DB i do a sql select statement and it doesnt read the new rows inserted. I dont know what could be the issue because in sqlite studio i do the same select statement after my app does the inserts and i get the data.

I have already read about that i have to copy a resource database to another folder so that i can read/write it, but doesnt work either.

Do you have any idea?

My opening code is something like this.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writablePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DatabaseName.sqlite"];
//this is the copy db from the resource database
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writablePath];
```

And here is the code that does the inserts and deletes.

```
 if([db open]){
    for (int i = 0; i < [updatedData count]; i++) {
        z_ent = [((NSNumber *)([[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ent"])) intValue];
        z_opt = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"opt"]) intValue];
        zaniocorte = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"anioCorte"]) intValue];
        zmescorte = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"mesCorte"]) intValue];
        zestatus = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"estatus"]) intValue];
        zidcontraparte = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"idContraparte"]) intValue];

        zconsumomesa = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"consumo"]) doubleValue];
        zconsumototal = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"consumoTotal"]) doubleValue];
        zlinea = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"linea"]) doubleValue];
        zlineadisponible = [((NSNumber *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lineaDisponible"]) doubleValue];

        zcontraparte = ((NSString *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"contraparte"]);
        zinstitucion = ((NSString *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"institucion"]);
        zmesa = ((NSString *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"mesa"]);
        ztiporiesgo = ((NSString *)[[updatedData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"tipoRiesgo"]);

        queryUpdateInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ZTESORERIACONSOLIDADO
 (Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZANIOCORTE, ZMESCORTE, ZCONSUMOMESA, ZCONSUMOTOTAL, ZESTATUS, ZLINEA, ZLINEADISPONIBLE, ZCONTRAPARTE, ZIDCONTRAPARTE, ZINSTITUCION, ZMESA, ZTIPORIESGO) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, '%@', %d, '%@', '%@', '%@');",z_ent, z_opt, zaniocorte, zmescorte, zconsumomesa, zconsumototal, zestatus, zlinea, zlineadisponible, zcontraparte, zidcontraparte, zinstitucion, zmesa, ztiporiesgo];

        queryUpdateDelete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM ZTESORERIACONSOLIDADO WHERE ZMESCORTE = %d AND ZANIOCORTE = %d", zmescorte, zaniocorte-1];

        del = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateDelete];
        ins = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateInsert];
    }
}
[db close];
```

Comment: Are you closing the cursor after inserting?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations based upon the code you have now provided.

1. Examine return values.

   You should be examining the `del` and `ins` return values from [`executeUpdate`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/executeUpdate%3a) and if either is `NO`, you should examine [`lastErrorMessage`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/lastErrorMessage):

   ```
   del = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateDelete];
   if (!del)
       NSLog(@"%s: executeUpdate delete error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

   ins = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateInsert];
   if (!ins)
       NSLog(@"%s: executeUpdate insert error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);
   ```
2. Do not use `stringWithFormat`.

   You really should not use `stringWithFormat` to build the SQL, but rather use the `?` placeholders in your sql, and then pass the parameters to `executeUpdate`:

   ```
   queryUpdateInsert = @"INSERT INTO ZTESORERIACONSOLIDADO (Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZANIOCORTE, ZMESCORTE, ZCONSUMOMESA, ZCONSUMOTOTAL, ZESTATUS, ZLINEA, ZLINEADISPONIBLE, ZCONTRAPARTE, ZIDCONTRAPARTE, ZINSTITUCION, ZMESA, ZTIPORIESGO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

   queryUpdateDelete = @"DELETE FROM ZTESORERIACONSOLIDADO WHERE ZMESCORTE = ? AND ZANIOCORTE = ?";

   del = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateDelete, @(zmescorte), @(zaniocorte-1)];
   if (!del)
       NSLog(@"%s: executeUpdate delete error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

   ins = [db executeUpdate:queryUpdateInsert, @(z_ent), @(z_opt), @(zaniocorte), @(zmescorte), @(zconsumomesa), @(zconsumototal), @(zestatus), @(zlinea), @(zlineadisponible), zcontraparte, @(zidcontraparte), zinstitucion, zmesa, ztiporiesgo];
   if (!ins)
       NSLog(@"%s: executeUpdate insert error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);
   ```

   Please note the replacement of the `printf` style formatters with `?` SQL placeholders.

   Also note that the `executeUpdate` expects `NSNumber` objects instead of primitive numeric data types. So, in my example above, where you're storing the values in `NSNumber` and `double` variables, I had to use `@()` to get `NSNumber` representations. Even better, rather than retrieving the `NSNumber` from `convertedData`, converting that to a primitive data type such as `NSInteger` or `double` and then converting back to a `NSNumber`, just pass the original object returned from `valueForKey` and lose the `@()` altogether. You'd obviously have to change the data type for the variables if you did that, but it's a far more logical approach.)

   The key take-home message though is that you want to avoid needing to escape any special characters in your string (as well as protect yourself against SQL injection attacks) by using the parameters to `executeUpdate` rather than `stringWithFormat`. (The use of the additional parameters in `executeUpdate` is like using `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls in the SQLite library, itself.)
3. Is this a CoreData database?

   Do I infer from the `Z` in the table names and the column names that this is a CoreData database? If so, unless you've retired CoreData entirely, I wouldn't advise interacting directly with the database via SQLite (whether via FMDB or `sqlite3_xxx` calls). Certainly if you have CoreData open while you attempt this FMDB code, you could have problems (which will be illuminated when you look at the `lastErrorMessage`).
4. If using SQLite, though, use transactions.

   If you want to refine your algorithm (once you've identified and fixed the source of your bug), you may want to wrap all of this inside a `inTransaction` call, because if you're doing this with lots of records, you can get a significant performance gain.